# How can I use USBmakebmRequestType with DriverKit

Tags: c++, macos, iokit, ipados, driverkit

I'm building a driver in C++ for my iPad using DriverKit.

I'm trying to make a request to a control endpoint, so I'm trying to use [`IOUSBHostInterface::DeviceRequest()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbdriverkit/iousbhostinterface/3182582-devicerequest). For the first parameter, `bmRequestType`, the documentation states:

> `bmRequestType`
>
> The characteristics of the device request. See the `USBmakebmRequestType` macro for information about how to construct this request.

But this macro `USBmakebmRequestType` is defined in `IOKit` > `USB.h`

I tried to `#include <IOKit/USB.h>` but it doesn't find the header.

Any idea?

Comment: The correct path is `<IOKit/usb/USB.h>`.

Comment: Thanks. It still says `IOKit/usb/USB.h` file not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, that macro isn't available in USBDriverKit. I think the documentation is just a copy-paste from elsewhere. (kernel headers, most likely)

In my code I've simply bitwise or'd (`|`) different combinations of the various relevant constants from the header `<USBDriverKit/AppleUSBDefinitions.h>`:

```
enum tIOUSBDeviceRequest
{
    // […]
    // Pick one each of direction…
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionOut       = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionValueOut << kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionPhase),
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionIn        = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionValueIn << kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionPhase),
    // […]
    // …request type…
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeStandard       = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeValueStandard << kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypePhase),
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeClass          = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeValueClass << kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypePhase),
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeVendor         = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeValueVendor << kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypePhase),
    // […]
    // …and recipient:
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientDevice    = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientValueDevice << kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientPhase),
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientInterface = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientValueInterface << kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientPhase),
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientEndpoint  = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientValueEndpoint << kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientPhase),
    kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientOther     = (kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientValueOther << kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientPhase),
}
```

So, something like:

```
const uint8_t request_type =
  kIOUSBDeviceRequestTypeVendor
  | kIOUSBDeviceRequestRecipientDevice
  | kIOUSBDeviceRequestDirectionIn;
```

Comment: Nice, thanks @pmdj as always, the right answer :)